# Problems with google maps type different coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My GPS provides these coordinates "0023 36.8620 S, W 0046 38.1003"
But I can not put them in the Google Maps API seems that he does not accept this type, what is wrong? will he accept? or need to convert? how I can convert ?

[https://maps.google.com.br/maps?q=0023+36.8620+S,+0046+38.1003+W](https://maps.google.com.br/maps?q=0023%2036.8620%20S,%200046%2038.1003%20W)

```
var coordenadas= [{
            "Latitude": "0023 30.1119 S",
            "Longitude": "0046 42.3806 W",
            "Velocidade": "0.00",
            "Data": "2013-04-29 20:05:09"
        }, {
            "Latitude": "0023 30.1672 S",
            "Longitude": "0046 42.4452 W",
            "Velocidade": "21.00",
            "Data": "2013-04-29 20:31:05"
        }, {
            "Latitude": "0023 31.6420 S",
            "Longitude": "0046 46.3419 W",
            "Velocidade": "0.00",
            "Data": "2013-04-29 20:45:01"
        }, {
            "Latitude": "0023 31.4505 S",
            "Longitude": "0046 46.1651 W",
            "Velocidade": "155.00",
            "Data": "2013-04-29 21:01:19"
        }, {
            "Latitude": "0023 36.6380 S",
            "Longitude": "0046 40.4935 W",
            "Velocidade": "299.00",
            "Data": "2013-04-29 21:15:05"
        }, {
            "Latitude": "0023 36.8620 S",
            "Longitude": "0046 38.1003 W",
            "Velocidade": "0.00",
            "Data": "2013-04-29 21:45:06"
        }
    ];


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-23.5525, -46.638851),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var image = 'beachflag.png';
    $.each(coordenadas, function (i, items) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(items.Latitude, items.Longitude),
            map: map,
            icon: image
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent();
                infowindow.open(map, items.Data);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        console.log(items);
    });
```

Sorry my english is so bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Maps uses Decimal Degrees (WGS84).

Your device should have a setting to display in this format.